# Some navigation properties not maintained in call to importEntities?

Tags: javascript, breeze

Breeze's [EntityManager](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/api-docs/classes/EntityManager.html) (javascript) has a pair of methods that we are using to implement undo functionality. As a dialog opens, we use [exportEntities](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/api-docs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_exportEntities) to take a snapshot of the `EntityManager`. If the user cancels out of the dialog, we call [importEntities](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/api-docs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_importEntities) and pass in the output from the call to `exportEntities`. We also pass in a `MergeStrategy` of `OverwriteChanges` to ensure that the version from the snapshot 'undoes' any changes in the target.

There is some extra logic required here because of the way that new (`Added`) entities with store generated keys are handled by `importEntities`.

> ...the new entities may be assigned new temporary key values. This can
>   happen if you import after shutting down and relaunching the
>   application. You should not assume that an imported entity will have
>   the same temporary key as it had when it was exported. A key value
>   change could be necessary to prevent the temporary key of an imported
>   new entity from conflicting with the temporary key value of an entity
>   that is already in the target manager.

See the section labelled 'Importing new entities' on the [Export and import entities](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/export-import.html) page.

**Note**: It does not seem necessary for the application to shut down and relaunch the application for this behavior to be applied (contrary to the documentation above).

Not only are new keys assigned, but these entities are imported as new instances. The existing instances remain - untouched - in the EntityManager. We manually remove these (and any others that were added after the snapshot was taken) once `importEntities` is finished.

We considered simply removing all of the entities prior to calling `importEntities` so that we would not have to selectively remove them afterwards but realised that this would mean we would have more work in terms of fixing up references to the original entity instances. As it is, references from outside of the EntityManager to the entities that we *do* remove need to be fixed manually.

At first blush, it looked as though navigation properties (references between entities in the `EntityManager`) were being maintained. I.e. Navigation properties that referenced an entity that was replaced during `importEntities` (because it had a temporary key) would be updated to point to the new entity. So although any references from outside of the `EntityManager` needed fixing, those within it did not.

We later found a case where the navigation properties are not maintained though. Consider this scenario.

entityA - `EntityState.Unchanged`

entityB - `EntityState.Added`

```
entityA.navigationPropery = entity
```

entityA - `EntityState.Modified`

entityB - `EntityState.Added`

Once `importEntities` completes, `entityB` has been replaced with a new instance that has a different temporary key to the original. I would expect `entityA.navigationProperty` to reference this new entity but it continues to hold a reference to the original entity. In our setup, where the original entity is manually detached from the `EntityManager` after `importEntities`, the navigation property ends up with a null reference and a temporary ID that does not match any entities in the `EntityManager`. Ultimately, this results in a foreign key violation in the database during `saveChanges`.

Note that we saw the navigation property being correctly maintained where entityA had the state `EntityState.added`.

I had a go a reproducing the problem in the [DocCode](http://breeze.github.io/doc-samples/doccode.html) tests but was not successful (the test passed). I am guessing that there is a difference in the implementations in C# and JavaScript? Is there some similar resource which targets JavaScript? Or some other, recommended means of reproducing problems?

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task ImportChangedEntityAndMaintainNavigationPropertyReferencesToIt()
{
    var manager = new EntityManager(_serviceName);
    await manager.FetchMetadata(); // Metadata must be fetched before CreateEntity() can be called

    var order = manager.CreateEntity<Order>(new {OrderID = 1}, EntityState.Unchanged);
    //var order = manager.CreateEntity<Order>(EntityState.Unchanged);

    var employee = manager.CreateEntity<Employee>();

    order.Employee = employee;

    var exportData = manager.ExportEntities();

    var imported = manager.ImportEntities(exportData, new ImportOptions(MergeStrategy.OverwriteChanges));

    var importedOrder = imported.ImportedEntities.OfType<Order>().Single();

    Assert.AreSame(order, importedOrder);

    var managerOrder = manager.GetEntities<Order>().Single();

    Assert.AreSame(order, managerOrder);

    Assert.AreEqual(importedOrder.Employee.EntityAspect.EntityState, EntityState.Added);
    Assert.AreNotSame(importedOrder.Employee, employee); //Entities with temporary keys are replaced with new instances.
    Assert.IsFalse(importedOrder.Employee.EntityAspect.EntityKey.Equals(employee.EntityAspect.EntityKey)); //Entities with temporary keys are assigned new ones.
}
```

How can we ensure that all navigation properties are maintained?

Is there some other approach that we could take to implement undo which would not have this problem (and maybe not require us to have to manually fix external references to entities)?

**Note**: We are using `breeze-client` version 1.3 which is currently the most recent version on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/breeze-client).

Answer (score 0):

As far as Breeze knows, an import bundle could have been created at any time in the past, and for any reason.

So Breeze defensively assumes that any entities in the import bundle that are in the `Added` state are *not really the same*
as any similar entities that are already in the cache.  If they have the same temporary keys as entities in the cache,
then the imported entities will get new temporary keys so that they will not conflict with any existing temporary
keys.

As you've observed, Breeze *does* merge other entities (those in the `Deleted`, `Modified`, or `Unchanged` states).
So a *possible* workaround for your problem is to:

1. Before exporting, change all entities in the `Added` state to `Modified`
2. Export
3. Perform any edits on the entities
4. If "undo" is required, import
5. Repeat 1-4 as necessary
6. Before calling `SaveChanges`, process each entity with a negative key value:

   - If the entity is now `Modified`, change to `Added`
   - If the entity is now `Deleted`, change to `Detached`

The downside of this is if anything in your UI treats `Added` entities differently from `Modified` ones, it won't work.  You would need to put a separate flag on the entity to tell the UI that it's really added.

I will look into the possibility of adding a flag on `importEntities` that will allow for merging of `Added` entities that
have the same temporary key.

**UPDATE:** The `mergeAdds` flag has been added in breeze 1.7.0.  So now you can do this:

```
entityManager.importEntities(exportData, {   
    mergeAdds: true,
    mergeStrategy: breeze.MergeStrategy.OverwriteChanges
});
```

to merge added entities that have the same key.

Comment: Perfect. I will start looking at upgrading to try it out. Thanks!